# ADO.net connector: Delete command return Invalid value for column: Expected INT64

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Hey guys anyone run into this issue where the ADO.net connector returns "Invalid value for column: Expected INT64" when the column parameters are ordered in some other ways:

> Error details:
>   "Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution.
>   Status(StatusCode=FailedPrecondition, Detail="Invalid value for column GeographyKey in table Table1: Expected INT64.")"

```
var qry = "DELETE Table1";
var col = new SpannerParameterCollection();
col.Add("CustomerKey", SpannerDbType.Int64, 0);
col.Add("EmailAddress", SpannerDbType.String, "some@email.com");
col.Add("GeographyKey", SpannerDbType.Int64, 37);
```

This one throws error on CustomerKey:

```
var qry = "DELETE Table1";
var col = new SpannerParameterCollection();
col.Add("EmailAddress", SpannerDbType.String, "some@email.com");
col.Add("GeographyKey", SpannerDbType.Int64, 37);
col.Add("CustomerKey", SpannerDbType.Int64, 0);
```

But when the columns are arrange this way, moving the GeographyKey and CustomerKey in the first list, it doesn't throw an error

```
var qry = "DELETE Table1";
var col = new SpannerParameterCollection();
col.Add("GeographyKey", SpannerDbType.Int64, 37);
col.Add("CustomerKey", SpannerDbType.Int64, 0);
col.Add("EmailAddress", SpannerDbType.String, "some@email.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

A delete mutation takes a KeySet as its only argument. A KeySet does not include the column names, only the values of the key. It is therefore required that you specify the key values in the order of the key columns of the table. Have a look here for a specification of the method that is being called under the hood: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.instances.databases.sessions/commit#Delete

I am not familiar with the ADO.NET connector, but even if you are able to specify key values using a combination of column name and value in the ADO.NET API, in the end only the key values will be sent to Cloud Spanner.

Comment: Those three columns are part of the KeySet. The table is created with PRIMARY KEY (GeographyKey, CustomerKey, EmailAddress). I'm just wondering why it would fail on columns ordering when the last column is INT64

Comment: It fails when the last column is INT64 because the last column of your PRIMARY KEY is a STRING column (EmailAddress). The problem is that even though you specify the column name in your code when creating the key set that is to be deleted, the column names are not sent to Google Cloud Spanner, and the key set is evaluated based on the order of the specified values. This means that you MUST specify the key values in the same order as the definition of the primary key (i.e. GeographyKey, CustomerKey, EmailAddress)